# Local trivialization of $\mathcal O(-1)$, proposition 2.2.6, complex geometry by Huybrechts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, online-resources, line-bundles

I was reading **Complex Geometry** by Daniel Huybrechts. On page 68, section 2.2 we have a proposition of holomorphic line bundle over $\mathbb P^n$,

> Proposition 2.2.6: The projection $\pi:\mathcal O(-1)\rightarrow\mathbb P^n$ is given by projecting to the first factor. Let $\{U_i\}_{i=0}^n$ be an open covering of $\mathbb P^n$. A canonical trivialization of $\mathcal O(-1)$ over $U_i$ is given by, $$\psi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i\times\mathbb C,\quad(\ell,z)\mapsto(\ell,z_i)$$
> The transition maps $\psi_{ij}(\ell):\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C$ are given by $w\mapsto \frac{z_i}{z_j}\cdot w$, where $\ell=(z_0:\cdots,z_n)$.

Suppose we have $(\ell,z^*)$ where $\ell$ belongs to $U_i$ and $z^*\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. In this scenario, I assumed that if we map $(\ell,z^*)$ using $\psi_j^{-1}$, it would look like this: $(\ell,z_0,\cdots,z_{j-1},z^*,z_{j+1},\cdots,z_n)$, inserting $z^*$ at position $j$. However, if this option doesn't hold, what alternatives should we consider? Because we need also to satisfy, $z\in \ell$. Now, $\psi_i(\ell,z_0,\cdots,z_{j-1},z^*,z_{j+1},\cdots,z_n)=(\ell,z_i)$. When we apply $\psi_i$ to $(\ell,z_0,\cdots,z_{j-1},z^*,z_{j+1},\cdots,z_n)$, fixing $\ell$, I noticed that the transition function $z^*\mapsto z_i$.

> **Question**: What I got doesn't match with the book. Where did I make the mistake?

Similarly, I want to tackle the same issue for sections: $\sigma_i$ in $\Gamma(U_i,\mathcal O(-1))$ and $\sigma_j$ in $\Gamma(U_j,\mathcal O(-1))$. Here, we're lifting $\ell$ from $\mathbb P^n$ to $\mathcal O(-1)$. So, we have $$U_j\times\mathbb C\stackrel{\psi_j}{\leftarrow}\pi^{-1}(U_i\cap U_j)\stackrel{\psi_i}{\rightarrow}U_i\times\mathbb C$$
and,
\begin{align}
\sigma_i&:U_i\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(U_i)\stackrel{\psi_i}{\cong}U_i\times\mathbb C\\
\sigma_j&:U_j\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(U_j)\stackrel{\psi_j}{\cong}U_j\times\mathbb C
\end{align}
Now, I couldn't get how the section $\sigma_i$ lift $\ell=(z_0:\cdots,z_n)\in U_i\cap U_j$, one possible way maybe
\begin{align}
\sigma_i(\ell)&=\left((z_0:\cdots,z_n),\frac{z_0}{z_i},\cdots,\frac{z_n}{z_i}\right)\stackrel{\psi_i}{\rightarrow}\boxed{(\ell,1)}\\
\sigma_j(\ell)&=\left((z_0:\cdots,z_n),\frac{z_0}{z_j},\cdots,\frac{z_n}{z_j}\right)\stackrel{\psi_j}{\rightarrow}\boxed{(\ell,1)}
\end{align}
Because $\mathcal{O}(-1):=\{(\ell,z)\in \mathbb{CP}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}: z\in \ell\}$, that's why I think the lifting might be $\in\mathbb{CP}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ (Let me correct if my understanding is wrong). Then I assume the transition map might be $\frac{z_j}{z_i}$ because $\sigma_i\mapsto \frac{z_j}{z_i}\cdot\sigma_j$ while fixing $\ell$. I think I do mistake on the trivialization part $\boxed{(\ell,1)}$ (Does the $1$ reflect the "matrix representation" mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148306/1167703)?).

> **Question**: I'm unsure if my computation is correct, can anyone verify that? And does the trivialization part play any role to get the transition maps?

My confusion arise since I haven't found any information on section for holomorphic bundles up until section 2.2, though I haven't covered everything since I'm studying the book on my own and skip most of the part which seems unfamiliar to me. It will be a great help if anyone suggest an answer or resource from where I can clear my understanding. TIA

Comment: Let me know if I need any modification to my question. It seems like I put so many text in a single thread. Do I need to split the question? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I haven't read all of it but this is nowhere near the scale of a "too long" question imo

Comment: @N00BMaster It seems we read the same reference at the moment. Have you looked the sections of this line bundle ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887317/global-sections-of-the-line-bundle-mathcalok-prop-2-4-1-huybrechts-m

Answer (score 2):

Your $\psi_j^{-1}$ is not quite right. We have
$$
\psi_j^{-1}: U_j\times {\mathbb C}\to \pi^{-1}(U_j);\ (\ell, w)\to (\ell, z),
$$
where $\ell = (z_0:\dots:z_j:\dots:z_n)$ with $z_j\neq 0$ by $\ell\in U_j$, and
$$
z=\frac{w}{z_j}(z_0, \cdots, z_j, \cdots, z_n) = \Big(\frac{z_0}{z_j}w,\cdots, w,\cdots, \frac{z_n}{z_j}w\Big).
$$

So $z\in {\mathbb C}^{n+1}$ is the unique vector on the line $\ell$ whose $j$th component is $w$. We do this by the multiplication of a suitable scale. Also note that we changed the homogeneous coordinates using $:$ in $\ell$ to ordinary coordinates using $,$ in $z$.

Then we see that
$$
\psi_{ij}=\psi_i\psi_j^{-1}: (\ell, w)\to (\ell, z)\to \Big(\ell, \frac{z_i}{z_j}w\Big),
$$
since that is the $i$th component of $z$.

That is why Huybrechts writes
$$
\psi_{ij}(\ell)(w)=\frac{z_i}{z_j}w,
$$
where $\ell=(z_0:\dots:z_n)\in U_i\cap U_j$.

---

Let me add a bit about sections. I don't think the $1$ you chose  would work. A local section
$$s_i: U_i\to \pi^{-1}(U)\overset{\psi_i}\to U\times {\mathbb C}$$ should satisfy
$$s_i(\ell) = \psi_{ij}(\ell) s_j(\ell)$$
to patch up to get a global section. In the ${\mathcal O}(-1)$ case, $\psi_{ij}(\ell)=\frac{z_i}{z_j}$. There are no global holomorphic sections, in this case.

However if you consider ${\mathcal O}(1)\to {\mathbb P}^n$, then
$$
\psi_{ij}(\ell)=\frac{z_j}{z_i}.
$$
Then
$$
s_i(\ell)=\frac{z_0}{z_i},
$$
where $\ell=(z_0:\dots:z_n)$ with $z_i\neq 0$, do define a holomorphic section as they patch. Indeed,
$$
s_i(\ell)=\frac{z_0}{z_i} = \frac{z_j}{z_i}\frac{z_0}{z_j} = \psi_{ij}(\ell)s_j(\ell). 
$$
Instead of $z_0$, using $z_k$ for $0\leq k\leq n$ gives $n+1$ holomorphic sections, which form a basis of
$$
\Gamma({\mathbb P}^n, {\mathcal O}(1)) = H^0({\mathbb P}^n, {\mathcal O}(1)) \ \text{ with dimension }\ h^0({\mathbb P}^n, {\mathcal O}(1))=n+1.
$$

For the original ${\mathcal O}(-1)$, choosing say
$$
s_i(\ell) = \frac{z_i}{z_0}
$$
only gives a meromorphic section, since on $U_i$, $z_0$ still has zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I got the clear picture, @Threeaggies. Could you confirm if my lifting for sections $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ is correct?

Comment: I edited the post, and hopefully it helps. It takes a while to get used to such calculations. But keep in mind that you need to define concrete numbers from a line $\ell$ with homogenous coordinates, so usually quotients of coordinates are required. Also the local sections need to patch up by the transition functions $\psi_{ij}$ to define something global. Then some sections are holomorphic and some are meromorphic, depending on if you divide by functions with zeros.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Yes, these calculations can be quite challenging, especially when you're working through them yourself. I'm considering delving into characteristic classes (specifically Chern classes) for $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to compare the differences between these bundles. Could you recommend a textbook or resource that provides detailed calculations for the projective case? Thanks again. @Threeaggies

Comment: I learned such things from Griffiths & Harris, but only after a long time they appear natural to me. Still, their book is more concrete than some others, and section 1.1 there can be useful.